# Mass test-connection powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, psobject

Well, I have problem with `Test-Connection` function in PowerShell.
I have a csv file with column `Server name` and `IPAddress`. I need to create connection report with information *Server name*, *IPAddress*, *Result*. How could I add information about column server name?

My current code looks like:

```
$Report = @()
$Servers = Import-CSV "C:\skrypt\bobi\servers.csv"  -Delimiter ';'
foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    if ($Alive = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server.IPAddress -Count 1 -quiet) {
        $TestResult = New-Object psobject -Property @{
            IPAddress = $Server.IPAddress
            Result    = "Online"
        }
    }
    else {
        $TestResult = New-Object psobject -Property @{
            IPAddress = $Server.IPAddress
            Result    = "Offline"
        }
    }
    $Report += $TestResult
}       
$Report | Select-Object IPAddress, Result | Export-Csv C:\skrypt\bobi\Report.csv -nti
```

Comment: How about adding `ServerName = $Server.ServerName` to the `psobject` instatntiations?

Comment: Oh, `$Alive` is assigned, but never used

Comment: Or `$Server."Server Name"` if the column name contains a space.

Comment: @Clijsters, what if csv list does not contain domain names of the servers?

Comment: That wasn't the question, was it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you:

```
$Servers = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Server Name' = 'Server1'
        IPAddress = '10.10.10.10'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Server Name' = 'Wrong'
        IPAddress = '10.10.10.999'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Server Name' = 'Server2'
        IPAddress = '10.10.10.15'
    }
)

$Report = foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    # First we collect all details we know in an object
    $Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name   = $Server.'Server Name'
        IP     = $Server.IPAddress
        Online = $false
    }

    # Then we do the test
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server.IPAddress -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        # If the connection is successful, we set it to True
        $Result.Online = $true    
    }

    # As a last step we return the complete object
    # where it is collected in the array of Report
    $Result
}

$Report | Select-Object Name, IP, Online
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your CSV file **have column with hostnames** you would need to change `PSCustomObject` to:

```
$TestResult = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    IPAddress = $Server.IPAddress
    HostName = $Server.HostName #assuming column name is "HostName"
    Result    = "Result"
}
```

In case your CSV file **does not have column with hostnames** you would need to request `System.Net.Dns` class with its `GetHostByAddress` method. Like so:

```
$TestResult = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    IPAddress = $Server.IPAddress
    HostName = $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($Server.HostName).HostName -join ';')
    Result    = "Result"
}
```

In both cases you then will need to pipe HostName property to export csv file

```
$Report | Select-Object IPAddress, HostName, Result | Export-Csv C:\skrypt\bobi\Report.csv -nti
```

Comment: Wow! Now its almost perfect. Are there any options in powershell to change colour of exported csv result? I mean for example: green for online and red for offline.

Comment: @MaciejObidziński, CSV files are meant to be just a set of raw values. No colors or formatting. If you want to perform some extra representives you will need to change CSV to Excel file and then color up cells/rows.

Comment: Ok, I found ImportExcel module and now script is complete. Thanks!

Comment: @MaciejObidziński, I am glad I could help you. Mark my answer as an answer so it might help somebody as well.